# Iterate through every file in one directory

Tags: ruby, directory, filesystems

How do I write a loop in ruby so that I can execute a block of code on each file?

I'm new to ruby, and I've concluded that the way to do this is a do each loop.
The ruby file will be executed from a different directory than the directory I want to loop through.

I've tried the `Dir.foreach` and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Can you specify what happened when you tried to make it work? What exact code did you try (or the relevant chunk, if it's long)? What error messages did you get? `Dir.foreach` works to iterate over the contents of a directory, so something else much be going on.

Comment: If you only want files within your directory, don't forget to test for files when iterating over the directory contents:  `do_something_with(entry) if File.file?(entry)`

Comment: Use `'img/*.{jpg,png,gif,jpeg}'` to grab multiple extensions.

Comment: @ChrisPeters seems unlikely unfortunately, as the OP hasn't been on the site in over four years.

Answer (score 465):

As others have said, [`Dir::foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-foreach) is a good option here. However, note that `Dir::foreach` and [`Dir::entries`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-entries) will always include `.` and `..` (the current and parent directories). You will generally not want to work on them, so you can use [`Dir::each_child`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-each_child) or [`Dir::children`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-children) (as [suggested by ma11hew28](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58276384/242933)) or do something like this:

```
Dir.foreach('/path/to/dir') do |filename|
  next if filename == '.' or filename == '..'
  # Do work on the remaining files & directories
end
```

`Dir::foreach` and `Dir::entries` (as well as `Dir::each_child` and `Dir::children`) also include hidden files & directories. Often this is what you want, but if it isn't, you need to do something to skip over them.

Alternatively, you might want to look into [`Dir::glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-glob) which provides simple wildcard matching:

```
Dir.glob('/path/to/dir/*.rb') do |rb_filename|
  # Do work on files & directories ending in .rb
end
```

Comment: Use `Dir.foreach` if the directory contains a huge number of files!

Comment: thanks! Small mod to make it even better: `next if File.directory? item`

Comment: @mr.buttons That won't always do the right thing. Sometimes people want to work on *directories* as well as files. I gave code for avoiding the special listings for `.` or `..` because people almost always want to ignore those two.

Comment: @Tilo: just out of interest, care to explain in a bit more detail why? :)

Comment: @mkataja `Dir.foreach` iterates rather than builds up a (potentially huge) array up front (which `Dir.glob` does). So if the directory is really huge, it can make a performance difference. Under normal circumstances you wouldn't notice, but under stress conditions, it can absolutely matter.

Answer (score 102):

This is my favorite method for being easy to read:

```
Dir.glob("*/*.txt") do |my_text_file|
  puts "working on: #{my_text_file}..."
end
```

And you can even extend this to work on all files in subdirs:

```
Dir.glob("**/*.txt") do |my_text_file| # note one extra "*"
  puts "working on: #{my_text_file}..."
end
```

Answer (score 33):

Dir has also shorter syntax to get an array of all files from directory:

```
Dir['dir/to/files/*'].each do |fname|
    # do something with fname
end
```

Comment: What in this code prevents directories from also being used with `fname`'s iterations?

Comment: For future googlers, and to answer @kayleeFrye_onDeck's question, nothing in the code so far limits `fname` to files only. Within the block itself, you can add any limitations you need through tests.

Answer (score 26):

```
Dir.foreach("/home/mydir") do |fname|
  puts fname
end
```

Comment: Alternatively use Dir#[] or Dir#glob

Answer (score 14):

The find library is designed for this task specifically:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html

```
require 'find'
Find.find(path) do |file|
  # process
end
```

This is a standard ruby library, so it should be available

Comment: `File.find` goes recursively down as far as it can, starting from whatever path you give it. I'm not sure that is what the OP wants.

Comment: I dont seem to have access to that method - Find.find ? Do I need to download a library ot include this functionality ?

Comment: @user470184: "Find" is a standard ruby library and should be available with the default ruby installation. However, you need to "require 'find'" before you can use it.

Comment: @Faisal Can I pass glob patterns like `*.rb` to `find()`

Answer (score 10):

To skip `.` & `..`, you can use [`Dir::each_child`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-each_child).

```
Dir.each_child('/path/to/dir') do |filename|
  puts filename
end
```

[`Dir::children`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-children) returns an array of the filenames.

Answer (score 9):

I like this one, that hasn't been mentioned above.

```
require 'pathname'

Pathname.new('/my/dir').children.each do |path|
    puts path
end
```

The benefit is that you get a Pathname object instead of a string, that you can do useful stuff with and traverse further.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dir.new('/my/dir').each do |name|
  ...
end
```

Comment: In addition to Dir.new('/my/dir') there's also Dir.entries('/my/dir') but Dir.foreach() is a bit more succinct.

Comment: @Z.E.D. Also `Dir.foreach` iterates while `Dir.entries` builds the whole array up at once. So if the directory is immense, it's less of a memory hit. (Not usually a big deal, probably, but still...)