# Display content of directory Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I display the file listing of a local directory in a Ruby On Rails application?

Comment: Content? What do you mean? List of files?

Comment: Stackoverflow has answers to most basic questions. As a rule of thumb, you should search for an answer before asking =)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512254/iterate-through-every-file-in-one-directory has plenty of answers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Dir.foreach("/path/to/your/dir") { |file|
        puts file
}
```