# Ruby/Watir : How do I reference multiple .yml files from the same Ruby file

Tags: ruby, watir

I am trying to retrieve key value pairs defined on two different .yml files. Is it possible to do so in a single Ruby file ?

Comment: Sure. Why not? Can you provide code so we can know your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Try this:

```
require 'yaml'
file1 = YAML.load_file("/home/abdo/settings.yml")
file2 = YAML.load_file("/home/abdo/database.yml")
```

This is an example I'm using in Rails to load a settings file:

```
SETTINGS = YAML.load_file("#{Dir.pwd}/config/settings.yml")[Rails.env]
```

If you want to load multiple files in 1 hash, you can do the following:

```
files = %w(database.yml settings.yml)
yamls = files.map { |f| YAML.load_file("#{Dir.pwd}/config/#{f}") }
H = files.each_with_object({}).with_index { |(e, hash), i| hash[e] = yamls[i] }
```

You can access `H["database.yml"]` to get the `Hash` representing the file with name `database.yml`

If you want to load a list of files following a certain pattern in a directory, you can use `Dir.glob` as mentioned in [Iterate through every file in one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512254/iterate-through-every-file-in-one-directory)

**EDIT** If your YAML files have non-conflicting data (data that does not get overridden when merged) and you'd like to merge all of them in a single `Hash`, you can do:

```
yamls.inject({}) { |hash, yaml| hash.merge(yaml) }
```

Comment: Thank you Abdo, The problem we are facing in our project is that there are 25-30 .yml configuration files. Is there any way for us to merge all the data present in these files in some way so that it can referenced by a single referencing variable ? We do not want to use a single .yml file for maintainability.

Comment: Code updated above =)