# How do I run this ruby code?

Tags: video, mp3, ruby

I'm using interactive ruby on windows 8.  I'm trying to attach an image to multiple mp3s in a folder and encode them to mp4.   How do I specify the folder, and how do I run this code in Ruby interactive or anywhere?

```
Dir.glob("*.mp3").each do |file|
    system("ffmpeg -i #{file} -loop 1 -i image.png -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest output.mp4")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

save the following as your_program.rb

```
Dir.glob('/path/to/dir/*.mp3').each do |file|
    system("ffmpeg -i #{file} -loop 1 -i image.png -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest output.mp4")
end
```

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512254/iterate-through-every-file-in-one-directory) for an explanation of iterating over files in a directory.

I can't quite verify the validity of your system call, I'll leave that to you. but when you are ready to give the ruby file a shot just run...

```
ruby /path/to/ruby/file/your_program.rb
```